# How to scanf commas, but with commas not assigned to a structure? C

Tags: c

I want to scanf input like: "John, Surname, 9999" and commas should not be assigned to the scanned variable; spaces at the end and start of input deleted... 
**Now to structure student_t in a shape of p->name, would be assigned "John," with this comma, instead of "John".** How to do it in a way that the user inserts comma like in input example, but it's not assigned to p->name?
I don't even know how to encloth with words my point. I'm hammering my head with this for about 50 hours now.

```
struct student_t
{
    char name[20];
    char surname[40];
    int index;
};

struct student_t* read(struct student_t* p, int *err_code)
{
*err_code=0;

printf("Please enter data in a format: '[Name], [Surname], [index]':\n");

int c=scanf("%s, %s, %i", &p->name, &p->surname, &p->index);
return p;
}

void show(const struct student_t* p)
{
printf("%s %s, %i\n", p->name, p->surname, p->index);
}
```

example input:

```
Name, Surname, 9999
```

output to this example:

```
Name Surname, 9999
```

instead, my output is something like:

```
Name, , 0
```

so first "comma" typed by the user is assigned to p->name, and whitespace is p->surname, second comma is probably p->index which is of 'int' type, maybe that's why it's 0.
If I do:

```
char comma1, comma2, space1, space2;
int c=scanf("%c%s%c%s%c%i%c", &space1, &p->name, &comma1, &p->surname, &comma2, &p->index, &space2);
```

output is:

```
ame, Surname,, 9999
```

edit1:
I thank everyone from the bottom of my heart. Now, I didn't mention that I also want to handle errors, though it might cast more light whether approach to decide. 
 
*err_code= 

0 -- everything is loaded to the structure properly 
1 -- something went wrong, eg. user did not use commas when typing in format:'[Name], [Surname], [index]'
2 -- only name loaded properly
3 -- name and surname loaded properly (index went wrong) 

Given that, I think that handling these errors using scanf would be quite problematic. 
In the topic I used "how to scanf" because I don't know how to properly express scanning data from user to structure. 
Now, following Stephan Lechner's wisdom, I attend this approach in a way:

```
char buffer[1024], *pch1, *pch2;

if (fgets(buffer,1024, stdin))
{
    pch1=strchr(buffer, ',');
    pch2=strrchr(buffer, ',');
    if (pch1!=pch2 && pch1!=NULL)
    {
        char *name = strtok(buffer,","); // returns pointer to the beginning of the token
        if (name) { //the place where "," is occured becomes a "NULL" character
            sscanf(name," %19s", p->name);  // skip leading spaces
            char *surname = strtok(NULL,",");
            if (surname) {
                sscanf(surname," %39s", p->surname); // skip leading spaces
                char *index = strtok(NULL,",");
                if (index) {
                    p->index = (int)strtol(index, NULL, 10);
                           } //else *err_code=3;
                         } //else *err_code=2;
                  } 
    } else *err_code=1;
}
```

Comment: This will be much easier if you _don't_ use `scanf`.  Use `fgets` and `strtok` instead.

Comment: `struct student_t` -> Please provide the declaration

Comment: Any special reason to use scanf over other methods?

Comment: No, no reason for scanf over other methods. (I need to handle errors: 0--all good, 1--sth went wrong eg. no commas when typing, 2-- surname&index loaded wrong, 3-- only index loaded wrong).
I used scanf because I didn't know other methods (I thought fgets is only for files). Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scanf` has several pitfalls, especially when using it for scanning several separated input fields using a single statement / format string. For example, the new line character is treated as a white space just as a blank, and this can achieve weird results when reading in multiple lines. Further, you'd probably want to protect your code from being broken by "too long" user input; so you'd write `"%19s ..."`, but then the remainder of the input will be passed to the next format specifier...

These pitfalls let people tend to say "use `fgets` and parse the input on your own, e.g. by using `strtok`. The code gets "longer", but you get much more control over edge cases.

See the following code using such an approach:

```
int main()
{
    struct student_t s;
    struct student_t *p = &s;

    char buffer[1000];
    if (fgets(buffer,1000, stdin)) {
        char *name = strtok(buffer,",");
        if (name) {
            sscanf(name," %19s", p->name);  // skip leading spaces
            char *surname = strtok(NULL,",");
            if (surname) {
                sscanf(surname," %39s", p->surname); // skip leading spaces
                char *index = strtok(NULL,",");
                if (index) {
                    p->index = (int)strtol(index, NULL, 10);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what if input is a name consisting of multiple words divided by whitespace, eg. _Arnold, G. Deep, 999_? If I understand, sscanf puts to p->surname what's under surname: _G. Deep_, however stops as the whitespace is approached?

Comment: ah, using sscanf(surname," %39[^\t\n]", p->surname); seems to change that; firstly I wrote that it does not but I had a mess in my code. Here're my attempts to further use this. Seems to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360247/how-to-detect-if-user-inserts-data-with-commas-in-a-desired-format-or-not/51360844#51360844 Hell yes, officialy it works :D

Answer (score 3):

You can specify to match everything **except commas**:

```
int c = scanf("%[^,], %[^,], %i", &p->name, &p->surname, &p->index);
```

Comment: You might use `" %[^,], %[^,], %i"` in order to skip any leading white spaces.

Comment: `%[` expects a pointer to char, but `&p->name` is a pointer to array of char (after the edits to question).

Answer (score 1):

Now that I have the declaration of `struct student_t` (and a glass of wine!)

It should be

```
 int c = scanf("%19[^,], %39[^,], %i", p->name, p->surname, &p->index);
```

And then check if `c` is 3

Comment: Input will not be scanned correctly if one actually enters more than 19 characters for `name`...

Comment: but you will not get buffer overrun