# C. Properly handling double pointers to function that mallocs a structure and returns pointer to it -- read, display, free in different functions

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, structure

The program works fine when I dynamically allocated memory in "main" function. Now I want to allocate in "read" function, but every attempt I fail miserably.

I think that my problem is in my "main" function: I can't figure out how to retrive a structure (pointer) from function "read" and then free it's dynamically allocated memory by function "destroy".

```
int main(void)
{
    int err_code;
    struct student_t** s=(struct student_t**)malloc(1024*sizeof(struct student_t*));
    **s = &read(err_code); //here is: error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand.
    //But I think that my problem is wider than just this error.

    if (s==NULL) {
        puts("Error\n");
    }

    display(s);
    destroy(s);

    return err_code;
}
```

What I tried to do: create a pointer of struct type, pointing to pointer to the structure, returned by "read" function. Then pass this **pointer to "destroy" function, to free the malloc'ed memory.

Functions. 
In function "read" users inserts data that is assigned to a structure. Returns pointer to the dynamically allocated structure or NULL if there was any error.

```
struct student_t* read(int *err_code)
{   printf("Insert data:\n");
    struct student_t* p = (struct student_t *)malloc(1024*sizeof(struct student_t));
    *err_code=1;
    if (p==NULL) {
        puts("Error\n");
        return NULL;
    }
//then it's supposed to read from user and assing to struct. Code below in links.
}
```

```
struct student_t {
    char name[20];
    char surname[40];
    int index;
};
```

Fuction frees dynamically allocated memory, unless "read" failed and returned NULL.

```
void destroy(struct student_t **s)
{
if (s!=NULL) free(s);
}
```

My display function. But my problems begin earlier, I think.

```
void display(const struct student_t **s) //here I'm unsure if it should be *s- or **s-function.
{
    if(s!=NULL) printf("%s %s, %i\n", (*s)->name, (*s)->surname, (*s)->index);
}
```

My "read" function is based on answers for my previous questions. It works when I properly allocated memory in "main". The code for "read" I use: [How to detect if user inserts data with commas (in a desired format) or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51360247/how-to-detect-if-user-inserts-data-with-commas-in-a-desired-format-or-not)
Other simplier "read" with which I was unable to handle all errors I wanted properly: [How to scanf commas, but with commas not assigned to a structure? C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343178/how-to-scanf-commas-but-with-commas-not-assigned-to-a-structure-c)

I really appreciate all help, everything is like a salvation for my 150 hours 
 struggle with one task.

Comment: Please make up your mind. Do you want to work with an array of `student_t` (what's your `read` function does) or with an array of `student_t*` (what's the rest of your code does)? These are different things and you cannot do a U-turn and change your mind mid-code. You need to decide before you start writing a line of code, and stick to your decision. Your array should be either `student_t*` or `student_t**` all the way through.

Comment: Thanks! Fixing "display" to work on array of `student_t` instead of `student_t*` and with the answer from Some programmer dude fixed my code's errors and returning values like `-12841928` just after typing from keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *two* errors:

1. The one you ask about is because you're doing it all wrong. The value returned by a function is a so-called *r-value*. It's so named because it can only be on the right-hand side of an assignment. It's a little more complicated than that, but the common test for an r-value or an *l-value* (something you can assign to, the *left*-hand side) is if its address can be taken with the address-of operator `&`. R-values can *not* have an address taken.

   The (simple) solution to this is simple:

   ```
   *s = read(err_code);
   ```
2. The second error is because `read` expects a pointer to an `int` as its argument, while you pass a plain `int` variable. Here you *should* use the address-of operator:

   ```
   *s = read(&err_code);
   ```

---

There are a few other problems, the biggest being the need for `s` to be a pointer to a pointer. Can't it just be a single-pointer, and then simply do

```
    struct student_t *s = read(&err_code);
```

Another problem is that in many systems there might already be an existing `read` function (most notably POSIX systems like Linux and macOS), so you will have conflicting declarations for that function.